# Creating Excel (.xlsx) files in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, excel, xlsx

I'm writing a Cocoa application and I'm trying to export to the Excel XML format (ISO/IEC 29500-1) which is basically a zip file with a bunch of XML files in it named with a `.xlsx` extension.

I've tried generating AppleScript and using `NSAppleScript` to create the Excel file, which works, but is slow and the user has to have Excel installed on their machine.

I was able to create a simple .xlsx Excel file by writing the XML to files in Objective C and zipping them up and renaming the zip to `.xlsx`. Excel could open the file, but Numbers threw an error trying to open the file I created. It seems Excel must have implemented all (or most of) the ISO/IEC spec, while Numbers may only open the Excel flavored version.

How to create working Excel files using Cocoa and Objective-c?

Comment: You could check out the [MSDN documentation of the XLSX file format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd922181(v=office.12).aspx). May that is of help to you...

Answer (score 11):

How about encapsulating HTML table in Excel file? I have checked that this works and I can open it with Excel.

```
NSURL * documentsDirectory = [NSFileManager.defaultManager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask].lastObject;
NSURL *file = [documentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"contacts.xls"];
NSString* string = @"<table><tr><td>FOO</td><td>BAR</td></tr></table>";
[string writeToFile:file.path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Comment: This does NOT create an xls (Excel) file. This creates an HTML fragment file.

Comment: This is a html, not xls

Answer (score 3):

I've worked with the [OpenOffice API](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/API) and it works great. I would suggest you work with that to create your Excel files. If you don't have time time/patience to do that, a workaround could be to have 2 links to export files, the XLSX version hack for the Excels of the world and then a separate exported CSV file for the Numbers application.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia offers some links to libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_that_supports_Office_Open_XML#Programmatic_support_2), which would probably give you a good start.

If the Office Open XML format isn't a requirement, and you don't need overly complex files exported, I also suggest checking saving the files as stylesheet formatted HTML which Excel can also read. A simple way to learn how to format the HTML you want as a spreadsheet is creating the file in Excel, and saving it as HTML.

Comment: It looks like you can wrap PHP's PHPExcel component within Objective-C.