# How to create a custom .xls file programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

I need the excel file in which Header has background color,text color, but I am not able to do so.
I am able to create csv file which can't be customized.
i tried to create the .xml file too but in any way I am not able to create the customized one as per the format.

Comment: If you really able to create xls file from objective-c cocoa, please share the code with us.

Comment: Actually I am not able to create .xls file, but I have created .csv file. I can share the code but I don't have enough reputation to post own answer within 8 hours, so I am trying to answer here in parts

Comment: NSString *csvString =@"ID,DATE,NATURE,MONTANT TTC,DEVISE";
for(int i=0;i<5 ;i++){
NSString *strTemp =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@,%@,%@",
                            
                            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"1"],
                            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",@"18/02/2013"],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",@"Taxi"],
                            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",@"234"],
                            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",@"$"]];

        csvString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n %@",csvString,strTemp];
    }

Comment: Here in above code we are making the whole spread sheet data as a string i.e csvString

Comment: NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Document Dir: %@",documentsDirectory);
    
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.csv", @"userdata"]]; //add our file to the path
    [fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:[csvString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] attributes:nil];

Comment: And here in the above code we are creating the .csv file and saving it in document directory.

Comment: Hey don't get upset about points. Edit others questinons and you will get 2 points :)   I know till now xls file cant be created. So I wondered from where and how you got.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587004/is-there-a-library-or-example-for-creating-excel-xlsx-files/21829735#21829735