# Export NSImage to Excel Sheet

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch

How can export an NSImage in excel Sheet?

When i try doing the below, The Microsoft Excel Application is unable to read the content.

```
NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep = [self.displayView bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:[self.displayView bounds]];
[imageRep setSize:self.displayView.frame.size];
                [self.displayView cacheDisplayInRect:[self.displayView bounds] toBitmapImageRep:imageRep];
NSImage *image1 = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(imageRep.pixelsWide, imageRep.pixelsHigh)];
[image1 addRepresentation:imageRep]; 
[[image1 TIFFRepresentation]
 writeToFile:@"AbsolutePath/ExportImageTest.xlsx"atomically:YES];
```

Can any one Suggest me how can i export a view converted to NSImage in excel sheet?

Comment: A TIFF is not an Excel spreadsheet. Why do you believe writing a TIFF with an .xlsx will turn it into one?

Comment: Yep you are right Brad, But can you help me in getting this done using NSImage on excel sheet, Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `writeToFile:automatically:` it saves tiff at that path, does not add it to xlsx.
You need to know what is the xlsx format and then decide how to write the file into it.

This may help:

[Creating Excel (.xlsx) files in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587004/is-there-a-library-or-example-for-creating-excel-xlsx-files)

Comment: The Link you shared shows up the way to put the <img> tag where the actual image should be present out side the excel sheet. I want an actual image to be in excel sheet.

Comment: can you use base64 in that img tag ?